# Click function executes current and previous functions code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

My problem is that the `.click` functions are like "bubbling" up. For example, if I stay on `hand1`, it goes to the `hitOrStay2` for `hand2`, which is correct. However, if I click the hit button to hit on `hand2`, it hits on both `hand1` and `hand2`, instead of just `hand2`. If I stay on both `hand1` and `hand2`, but hit on `hand3`, it hits on all 3 hands.

Important Note. Yes I did have only 1 `hitOrStay` function and 1 `tableOptions` function, but it was doing the same thing. After messing around trying to fix it, I decided to have a different function for each of the 3 hands. However, the `.hit`, `.stay` html buttons are still the same, only one of each.

If I can't fix this, I guess my only option would be to create separate hit and stay buttons for each hand, with different ID's/classes...?

Here's my js/jQuery code: (*I'm not looking for anyone to provide a working example, since there's too much that goes into this. I'd just like to know why this is happening. What are some ways to go about fixing it. Etc.*)

```
function hitOrStay(cards, hand, nHands) {
   var x = addValueOfCards(cards);
   var rt = hand.classhtml.toString();
   var choicemessage = $('<p class="choicemessage">You have ' + (x) + '. Do you want to hit or stay?</p>');
    if (x < 19) {
        $(choicemessage).appendTo('.message');
        $('.hit, .stay').fadeIn();
        $('.hit').click(function() {
            $('.hit, .stay').hide();
            cards.push(dealone(hand));
            $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
            hitOrStay(cards, hand);
        });
        $('.stay').click(function() {
            $('.hit, .stay').hide();
            $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
            if (nHands > 1) {
               tableOptions2(nHands); }
        });
        }
    else {
        $('<p>You Busted</p>').appendTo('.message');
        $(rt).find('.crd').detach();
        if (nHands > 1) {
            tableOptions2(nHands); }
    }
}

function hitOrStay2(cards, hand, nHands) {
   var x = addValueOfCards(cards);
   var rt = hand.classhtml.toString();
   var choicemessage = $('<p class="choicemessage">You have ' + (x) + '. Do you want to hit or stay?</p>');
    if (x < 19) {
        $(choicemessage).appendTo('.message');
        $('.hit, .stay').fadeIn();
        $('.hit').click(function() {
            $('.hit, .stay').hide();
            cards.push(dealone(hand));
            $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
            hitOrStay2(cards, hand);
        });
        $('.stay').click(function() {
            $('.hit, .stay').hide();
            $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
            if (nHands > 2) {
               tableOptions3(nHands); }
        });
        }
    else {
        $('<p>You Busted</p>').appendTo('.message');
        $(rt).find('.crd').detach();
        if (nHands > 2) {
             tableOptions3(nHands); }
    }
}

function tableOptions(nHands) {
        hitOrStay(hand1.cards, hand1, nHands);  
}

function tableOptions2(nHands) {
        hitOrStay2(hand2.cards, hand2, nHands);
}

function tableOptions3(nHands) {
        hitOrStay3(hand3.cards, hand3, nHands);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work

```
if (x < 19) {
    $(choicemessage).appendTo('.message');
    $('.hit, .stay').fadeIn();
    $('.hit').on('click', function() {
        $('.hit, .stay').hide().off();
        cards.push(dealone(hand));
        $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
        hitOrStay(cards, hand);
    });
    $('.stay').on('click', function() {
        $('.hit, .stay').hide().off();
        $('.message').find('.choicemessage').detach();
        if (nHands > 1) {
           tableOptions2(nHands); }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `.click()` does not remove other event handlers previously added.  You can use `.off()` (preferred in new versions of jQuery) or `.unbind()`.

```
$('.hit').off('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unbind` to remove all `click` events before adding the new events.

```
$('.hit').unbind('click');
```

this code snippet removes all the click events on that element. To make sure you are not unbinding other events, its always a good practice to have them in a namespace and `bind/unbind` only events in those namespace.